# OpenCL example of running a kernel on both CPU and GPU simultaenously

Tags: opencl

I know how to run a kernel on several GPU devices in one physical system and my algorithm works very well with that (example: discrete video card and GPU in the APU).

Is it possible to use the CPU of the APU at the same time w/o specifically breaking off part of the vector for the CPU (which I think would be difficult to estimate size of)?

Comment: How do  you estimate?

Comment: I think the GPU and CPU come up as separate devices of the opencl platform which owns them. Do you have a specific application/algorithm in mind? some are well suited for this, and others not so much.

Comment: The algorithm would be out of scope of this question. Just interested in properly initializing the devices for now.

Comment: I don't have an APU device to test this on, but I expect it to work like two separate GPU devices. Just use CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU | CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU in the clGetDeviceIds call.

Comment: Good idea, I will try that. You do not actually need an APU to test this, as any one CPU with any one GPU would be a correct setup to reproduce what I am looking to support. I was mentioning an APU only in the context of running on multiple GPU devices, as its graphics device appears to OpenCL as just another GPU besides the discrete video card. As long as APU's GPU is enabled in the BIOS, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU scales up to both GPUs.

Comment: My unsolicited opinion: I have had success with using a discrete GPU and a CPU together, but for the small performance gain it wasn't really worth the extra overhead and complexity in the code (different workgroup sizes/dimensions, events, etc). Maybe worth it to eek out that last bit of power from the machine -- depending on the algorithm.  eg: I have seen DGEMM computation that uses the CPU(s) to crunch the addition only, and save the matrix multiplication for the GPU(s).

Comment: Isn't type of apu's igpu, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACC ?

Comment: @mfa You are probably right, and running GPU+CPU might not give much performance boost, I just want to exhaust what OpenCL provides before diving into hand optimization. Appreciate the input!

Comment: re: "Isn't type of apu's igpu, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACC ?"  Possibly, but I suspect the AMD drivers present it as a normal radeon device. I really need to get one to play with...   I thought CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR was for devices more like xeon phi.

Comment: CPU good at branching and superscalarity so it can even be better for some works.